# Selecting the 5th record before and after a supplied id along with other conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to select the 5th record before and after a supplied id from a table with data like below.

What came to my mind is: `select id-5, id+10 from devTable where id = 10 and stateCode = 'CA';`

However, this does not actually give you the 5th id before and after the supplied id taking into account the stateCode, it simply seems to add /sub 5 to the supplied id. Do you know how this can be done the right way?

**Desired results**

```
supplied id = 10 and stateCode = CA
prev | next
2    | 16

supplied id = 9 and stateCode = NY
prev | next
NULL | NULL
```

**Data**

```
"id"  | "stateCode"
-------------------
"1"     "CA"
"2"     "CA"
"3"     "CA"
"4"     "CA"
"5"     "NY"
"6"     "NY"
"7"     "CA"
"8"     "CA"
"9"     "NY"
"10"    "CA"
"11"    "CA"
"12"    "NY"
"13"    "CA"
"14"    "CA"
"15"    "CA"
"16"    "CA"
```

Comment: Well, shoot. I tried to answer it, but then realized that it wasn't actually what you were asking.  I'd start with using some subqueries, and maybe the limit keyword if you're using MySQL, or a similar construct using subqueries if you're using something like Oracle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this with `UNION ALL` two queries having `LIMIT` of 6 for one because of `<=` and 5 for second

### To get 5 records before and after id= 10

```
(SELECT *  FROM devTable WHERE id <= 10 AND stateCode = 'CA' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *  FROM devTable WHERE id > 10 AND stateCode = 'CA' ORDER BY id ASC  LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY id
```

[**See that fiddle for 5 records before after 10**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95e3b/2)

### To get 5th record before and after id= 10

```
(SELECT *  FROM devTable WHERE id < 10 AND stateCode = 'CA' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4,1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT *  FROM devTable WHERE id > 10 AND stateCode = 'CA' ORDER BY id ASC  LIMIT 4,1)
ORDER BY id
```

[**See that fiddle for 5th record before and after 10**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95e3b/7)

### Showing records row wise

```
SELECT 
(SELECT id  FROM devTable WHERE id < 10 AND stateCode = 'CA' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 4,1) AS `prev`,
(SELECT id  FROM devTable WHERE id > 10 AND stateCode = 'CA' ORDER BY id ASC  LIMIT 4,1) AS `next`
```

[**Display 5th record before and after 10 row wise**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95e3b/17)

This solution  is not specific to only 5th record it can be used for ***nth record*** as well

### Example

```
(SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  devTable 
WHERE id < 10 
  AND stateCode = 'CA' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT (n - 1), 1) 

UNION ALL 

(SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  devTable 
WHERE id > 10 
  AND stateCode = 'CA' 
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT (n - 1), 1) 
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: You're close. Did you see my **Desired results**?

Comment: @jmenezes you want 5th record or 5 records before after 10 ?

Comment: 5th record before and after the supplied id. Sorry, I'll redo my question.

Comment: Thanks. I'll tweak this. Is there any chance of getting them to display side by side, rather than two rows, just like in my example `prev | next
2    | 16`

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle, query for 5th record before given id

```
select * from (select id, statecode,rownum as rw 
from devTable where statecode = 'CA' and id < 10  
order by id desc) a
where a.rw = 5 ;
```

query for 5th record after given id

```
select * from (select id, statecode,rownum as rw 
from devTable where statecode = 'CA' and id > 10  
order by id asc) a
where a.rw = 5 ;
```